# Is there a correct order to put $stmt->bind_param() when doing multiple entries in a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, is there a correct order to put **$stmt->bind_param()** when doing multiple entries in a database?

If i put **$stmt->bind_param()** outside the foreach loop, it works ok. But, when i put **$stmt->bind_param()** inside the foreach loop it also work fine!

So, my question is, which is the semantically correct order of inserting **$stmt->bind_param(**) ? Before or after the foreach loop? I'm trying to get it right the first time so i don't encountered problem down the road.

```
...
$stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
//$stmt->bind_param('ii', $id, $vtype); // THIS WORKS OK

foreach ($arr_secondarytype as $vtype) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $id, $vtype); // THIS ALSO WORK OK!
    $stmt->execute();

    $num_rows_inserted = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $error = $stmt->error;

    if ( !empty($error) ) {
        break;
    }
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: A good rule of thumb is never execute a query inside a loop

Comment: @Strawberry absolute nonsense

Comment: Parameter binding (which works by variable *reference*) is best done outside / before the loop. See http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php#example-1811

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure what part of that contradicts my statement

Comment: @Strawberry The part where the query is executed inside the loop